# adding button in particular column of data-grid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am working on vb.net windows application.i have a grid view ..i am populating my data grid view like this:

in load event i wrote code like this:

```
Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,d.empimage as Image from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid", con.connect)
        dt1 = New DataTable
        bSource = New BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        bSource.DataSource = dt1
        gv.DataSource = bSource
        gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
        gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
```

so my grid view like this:[image]

i want to add button in my image column..so i try code like this: but that is adding one more column.

```
 Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
        gv.Columns.Insert(6, btn).
```

so how i can add button in my image column

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the button name to this to work like so :

```
Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
btn.HeaderText = "Click Data"
btn.Text = "Click Here"
btn.Name = "btn"
btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
gv.Columns.Insert(6, btn)
```

Comment: this time adding new column..sir i dont want to add new column

Comment: i want to get button in image column

Comment: you can't insert button type cell on normal column it must be button column.

Comment: so i cant add button in my image column??

Comment: is there any way to declare that column is Buttoncolumn type?

Comment: this is ok,,,in this case how i can take button click event of this button

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for displaying the DataGridView:

```
Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn)
        btn.HeaderText = "Click Data"
        btn.Text = "Click Here"
        btn.Name = "btn"
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
```