# How to add Button inside field in datagrid in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want add buttom inside field like in the photo.
Where when I clicked into field show button and when clicked out field hide button
[image]

Comment: refer this link already it has answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155365/adding-button-in-particular-column-of-data-grid-view-in-vb-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding button in particular column of data-grid view in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155365/adding-button-in-particular-column-of-data-grid-view-in-vb-net)

Comment: no I want button show when I click inside field and hide when I click outside field

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, then we can help you.

Comment: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells)

Comment: What is the point of hiding it? You are inventing your own convention that will be awkward for users.